# Calmly energised

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

What's a term (one or two words) that describes someone who is calm and also has lots of energy (particularly a woman)? i.e. They are not necessarily extroverted nor do they expend a lot of energy all at once and then become exhausted. They are grounded, with a good supply of energy to get through life.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dynamo

Answer (score 1):

**[powerhouse](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/powerhouse)** (en.oxforddictionaries.com)

noun

> 1. a person or thing of great energy, strength, or power.
>
>    "she appears to be an intellectual powerhouse"

Answer (score 0):

If you’re willing to accept metaphors, consider ***marathon runner***
(or the one-word alternative, [***marathoner***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marathoner)). 
A [marathon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathon) is literally a running race of 42.195 kilometers<sup>1</sup>. 
The word is used metaphorically to refer to any long-duration activity
(in contrast to a *sprint*). 
For example, [Stack Exchange’s recent four-year effort
to support HTTPS throughout the site](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/) easily qualifies as a marathon.

Long-distance running requires a lot of energy,
to be doled out gradually over a long period of time. 
In other words, long-distance runners require *stamina*. 
And then there’s this:

> A runner will typically have a lower pulse and blood pressure
>   than someone who isn’t as fit
>   because a runner’s body is able to work more efficiently,
>   notes Lawrence Horwitz, a cardiologist and professor of medicine
>   at the University of Colorado Health Sciences Center in Denver.
>                   — [LIVESTRONG.COM](http://www.livestrong.com/article/177432-the-normal-pulse-blood-pressure-for-a-runner/)

As far as I know,
there terms do not imply anything about personality or philosophy of life,
and they are not sex-specific.
____________
<sup>1</sup> Somewhat amusingly (to those who are amused by this kind of thing),
[Google’s Units Converter](https://www.google.com/search?q=1+marathon+in+km) recognizes a “marathon” as a unit of distance,
along with more traditional units such as “mile”, “foot”, “inch”,
“Ångström”, “furlong”, “light-year”, and [many more](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/3284611?hl=en#unitconverter). 
So, for example,
[1 typesetting (PostScript) point equals 8.36065e-9 marathons](https://www.google.com/search?q=1+postscript+point+in+marathons).